# C++: Efficiently access random vector positions

Tags: c++, random, vector, srand

So I have written some code to randomly access 5 positions of a vector.
I have done this by essentially populating one vector from a file, then creating a second vector to hold the random 5 elements of the first

*Populate 1st vector from file*

```
std::vector<std::string> ElemAlg::GetQuiz(int quizNo)
{
    std::ifstream fin("1.txt");

    while (std::getline(fin, question))
    {
        questions.push_back(question);
    }

    return questions;
}
```

*Access 5 random elements from the 1st vector and copy them to new vector*

```
std::vector<std::string> ElemAlg::AllocateQuestions()
{
    unsigned int seed = time(0);
    std::ifstream infile("rand.txt");
    if (infile)
    {
        infile >> seed;
        infile.close();
    }

    srand(seed);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        seed = rand();
        unsigned int randomIndex = seed % questions.size();
        selectedQuestions.push_back(questions[randomIndex]);
    }

    std::ofstream outfile("rand.txt");
    outfile << seed;
    outfile.close();

    return selectedQuestions;
}
```

Is this a *relatively* efficient way of doing this, do I need 2 vectors? Or have I completely over complicated a simple problem?

Is there a way to test the efficiency of it?

Thanks for anyones time. (note I am aware duplications of randomIndex is possible)

Comment: What is the type of `selectedQuestions`? You can make it `vector<const string *>` or `vector<vector<string>::const_iterator>` to avoid copying the string. But for 4 strings it's probably not worth it. You could also output to the file within your for loop - no need to keep a running store of strings. Please note that rand is usually poor quality and the % trick doesn't always give an even distribution.

Comment: I just noticed you are returning `selectedQuestions`. If you follow my suggestion you need to ensure the `questions` vector lives long enough so that pointers/iterators to it remain valid whenever you use `selectedQuestions`

Comment: If you want more efficiency, consider not copying the questions.

Comment: After loading the questions into your vector, you could then select an index at random and *remove* that question after you use it.